# Anyone using hadoop_fdw with cloudera 5.2.0?

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hive, cloudera-cdh, foreign-data-wrapper

After painful installation of hadoop_fdw into our running pgsql 9.3.4, I am trying to connect it to cloudera cluster 5.2.0 with no luck.

Is there a way of debugging the fdw? After creating the foreign table and selecting from it, I just got an error - ERROR: failed to connect to Hive: No more data to read.

btw.: Some old version of hadoop_fdw was capable of using url (jdbc://server:port/args), but not the recent version, there's just address & port.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop_fdw didn'd make it. There's probably something wrong/old/obsolete in hive.c. But with even more effort we managed to make jdbc_fdw work with cloudera jdbc drivers. The steps were as follows:

1) install jdbc_fdw extension

2) merge all driver jar files into one

3) `CREATE SERVER cloudera2 FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER jdbc_fdw OPTIONS(drivername 'com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver',url 'jdbc:hive2://fqdn:10000;user=hive',querytimeout '15', jarfile '/opt/cloudera/combined.jar');`

mental note: `set client_min_messages to debug5;` can help you identify where is the problem e.g.:driver not found etc